# Swift 2 Symbol Documentation Markup Syntax doesn't work with /** */

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I don't know why, but wit my xcode version (7.0), when I write this code documentation:

```
/**
Another description

- important: Make sure you read this

- parameter anInt: The number of times to cheer
*/
func commentBlockExample(anInt: Int) {

}
```

I get this:

[image]

If I write it down like this:

```
/// Another description

/// - important: Make sure you read this

/// - parameter anInt: The number of times to cheer
func commentBlockExample(anInt: Int) {

}
```

I get:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Both versions work identical in my Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: Anyone with Xcode 7 to confirm it's my installed version? I'm downloading the 7.0.1...

Comment: Same with Xcode 7.0.1. My problem comes from somewhere else. Might it be some installed plugins?